# Spring Batch Itemwriter Interface fix

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, itemwriter

The write method of Itemwriter has been changed in the spring version 5.

```
@Override
public void write(List<? extends List<DataDTO>> items) throws Exception{
    for(List<DataDTO> sublist:items){
        writer.write(sublist);
}
```

The above writer is FlatFileItemWriter.

I changed to the following

```
@Override
public void write(Chunk<? extends List<DataDTO>> items) throws Exception{
    for(List<DataDTO> sublist:items){
        writer.write((Chunk<? extends DataDTO>)sublist);
    }
}
```

Is this correct way of replacing/fix? need some help.

Im expecting the correct fix.

Expecting coreect replacement.

Comment: Hello Arun, did this answer work for you yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Spring Batch 5.0 migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide), most references to `List`s in the API were replaced with `Chunk`.

> - The signature of the method `ItemWriter#write(List)` was changed to `ItemWriter#write(Chunk)`
> - All implementations of `ItemWriter` were updated to use the `Chunk` API instead of `List`
> - All methods in the `ItemWriteListener` interface were updated to use the `Chunk` API instead of `List`
> - All implementations of `ItemWriteListener` were updated to use the `Chunk` API instead of `List`
> - The constructor of `ChunkRequest` was changed to accept a `Chunk` instead of a `Collection` of items
> - The return type of `ChunkRequest#getItems()` was changed from `List` to `Chunk`

A good way to do the migration in your code is to use one of `Chunk`'s [constructors](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/Chunk.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.List)).

Example:

```
@Override
public void write(Chunk<? extends List<DataDTO>> items) throws Exception{
    for(List<DataDTO> sublist:items){
        writer.write(new Chunk<>(sublist));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you it worked prefectly fine !